# Lightbox2 wanting to move the caption to the right of the image

Tags: javascript, html, css, lightbox, lightbox2

I'm trying to move the caption, what's in `data-title`, from underneath the image to the right of the image.

I don't know HTML/CSS very well, but it seems to me like the image is contained in the div `.lb-outerContainer`, and the caption is in the div `.lb-dataContainer` in the [Lightbox CSS](https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/blob/master/dist/css/lightbox.css). I tried removing the `clear: both` from the `::after` for `outerContainer` and adding `display: inline-block` to the two divs, but it didn't work. The image moved to the left but the caption didn't move up.

Does anyone have any advice? Thank you :)

Comment: Did you try to float the img and the caption to the left?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to put some custom css styling, also add a inner div in js file like following example code.

```
Find in js file - 

"<div id="lightboxOverlay" class="lightboxOverlay"></div><div id="lightbox" class="lightbox"><div class="lb-outerContainer"><div class="lb-container"><img class="lb-image" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" /><div class="lb-nav"><a class="lb-prev" href="" ></a><a class="lb-next" href="" ></a></div><div class="lb-loader"><a class="lb-cancel"></a></div></div></div><div class="lb-dataContainer"><div class="lb-data"><div class="lb-details"><span class="lb-caption"></span><span class="lb-number"></span></div><div class="lb-closeContainer"><a class="lb-close"></a></div></div></div></div>"


And Replace With(copy without Quats) - 

"<div id="lightboxOverlay" class="lightboxOverlay"></div><div id="lightbox" class="lightbox"><div class="new-inner-div"><div class="lb-outerContainer"><div class="lb-container"><img class="lb-image" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" /><div class="lb-nav"><a class="lb-prev" href="" ></a><a class="lb-next" href="" ></a></div><div class="lb-loader"><a class="lb-cancel"></a></div></div></div><div class="lb-dataContainer"><div class="lb-data"><div class="lb-details"><span class="lb-caption"></span><span class="lb-number"></span></div><div class="lb-closeContainer"><a class="lb-close"></a></div></div></div></div></div>"


New Style on page - 
    <style>
        .lightbox {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 10000;
        font-weight: 400;
        max-width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .new-inner-div
    {
        max-width: 700px;border: 1px solid red;margin: 0 auto;min-height: 346px; background: #fff;
    }
    .lb-outerContainer
    {
        width: 50% !important; height: auto !important;float: left;
    }
    .lb-dataContainer
    {
        float: right;width: 46% !important;
    }
        .lb-data .lb-close {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        text-align: right;
        outline: 0;
        filter: alpha(Opacity=70);
        opacity: .7;
        -webkit-transition: opacity .2s;
        -moz-transition: opacity .2s;
        -o-transition: opacity .2s;
        transition: opacity .2s;
    }
    .lb-image
    {
    width:100% !important;
    }
    </style>
```